# WiX: Compare version "7.x.x.x" and "10.x.x.x"

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX file where I have to do a version comparison to check prerequisites. The expression looks something like this:

```
<Publish (attributes...)>
    <![CDATA[(VERSION<"7.0") OR (other expressions)]]>
</Publish>
```

This was working fine until now as the major version numbers went 7 to 8 to 9. We are now moving to version 10 and the string comparison is failing as "1" is less than "7". I would like `"10.0"<"7.0"` to evaluate to `false` as I intend to compare versions, but the expression evaluates to `true` because of the string comparison that is happening.

I have checked several StackOverflow answers as well as WiX documentation, but it seems like a version comparison operation is missing.

Ideally, in a programming language, if there was no version parsing mechanism, I would split the string by the `.` and converted the string to integer and compared the corresponding entries.

What approach can I use for WiX?

Comment: You declare your condition inside CDATA, but WiX has variables with version type. You can define them and use to comparison. Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097231/how-to-compare-version-variables-in-detectcondition-in-burn-wix)

Comment: Note: the version type variables only exist in Bundles. The Windows Installer did not (unfortunately) choose to include a version type in the MSI package engine. :(

Comment: It is an MSI that is generated in my case

Answer (score 0):

***MSI SDK***: Yes, as the MSI SDK states: *"**`Note that the installer will not do direct comparisons of the Version data type in conditional statements`**. For example, you cannot use comparative operators to compare versions such as "01.10" and "1.010" in a conditional statement. Instead use a valid method to search for a version, such as described in [Searching for Existing Applications, Files, Registry Entries or .ini File Entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/searching-for-existing-applications-files-registry-entries-or--ini-file-entries), and then set a property."*

The question remains if searching and setting properties is a viable approach for you. You can also use a custom action and inspect the system in more flexible ways - if you really need to.

What exactly are you doing in that Publish element?

Comment: It enables/disables certain options based on the condition. Thanks for the link, will update if it works.