# Registry changes in patch moved to WOW6432Node key for 64-bit msi in Installshield QuickPatch project

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, patch

I am trying to create patch(.msp) with some registry changes using InstallShield QuickPatch project. But the registry changes moved to WOW6432Node key, however msi used as baseline was 64-bit.

Comment: [Maybe have a quick look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57048822/129130). Is the component set 64-bit?

Comment: In the property page for the component look for `64-bit component` = `yes` or `no`.

Comment: My personal opinion: avoid QuickPatch. Create a patch by building a minor upgrade and then using the patch design view.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul 64-bit component is not set when i check the .msp file.When updating it manually , it works fine. But problem is there is no option in QuickPatch for setting component 64-bit.

Comment: @MichaelUrman We can't avoid QuickPatch for now as we have automated the process for quickpatch as there are hundreds of patches build using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with InstallShield QuickPatch project. Support had confirmed that.