# How to compare two versions in wix

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

```
<PackageGroup Id="happ">
    <ExePackage Id="happ"
      SourceFile="..\Products\happ\setup.exe"
      SuppressSignatureVerification="yes"
      PerMachine="yes"
      Cache="always"
      UninstallCommand="/CMD/UNINSTALL,quiet"
      DetectCondition='(InstalledHAppVersion = HAppVersion) AND (NOT UPGRADINGBUNDLECODE)'
      InstallCondition="(HAppVersion &lt;= InstalledHAppVersion) OR (NOT InstalledHAppVersion)"
      InstallCommand= "/CMD/[happ_CMD],progfilepath=&quot;[happ_progfilepath]&quot;,datapath=&quot;[happ_datapath]&quot;,serveruser=[happ_serveruser],startservices=[happ_startservices],dataarchiverport=[happ_dataarchiverport],firewall=[happ_firewall]"
      RepairCommand= "/CMD/[happ_CMD],progfilepath=&quot;[happ_progfilepath]&quot;,datapath=&quot;[happ_datapath]&quot;,serveruser=[happ_serveruser],startservices=[happ_startservices],dataarchiverport=[happ_dataarchiverport],firewall=[happ_firewall]">
      <PayloadGroupRef Id="happPayloadGroup"/>
    </ExePackage>
  </PackageGroup>
```

Here `InstalledHAppVersion` is `9.1.383.0` and `HAppVersion` is `10.0.436.0`
Previously `InstallCondition` worked fine as string comparison becuase major version was only one character but now it is of two characters which fails the string comparison of versions.

I didn't find anything in wix doc to convert or typecast string type to version type which is the main cause, Any help to resolve would be great

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to compare version variables in DetectCondition in burn (wix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097231/how-to-compare-version-variables-in-detectcondition-in-burn-wix)

Comment: No, I already have two string variables and want to convert them to version type or create two new version type variables based on existing string varaibles

Comment: I'm not a WixToolset expert, but to me that is what it looks like what you nee is to set the attribute: type="version" as their docs and the previous question shows
 https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/variable.html

Comment: Unfortunately, version type is getting changed to string, while assigning value to variable from registry which is of string type

Comment: Can you explain why `HAppVersion` is a string Variable? Normally this is known at build time and can be a version Variable in the source code. If you compare a string Variable to a version Variable then it's supposed to coerce the string to a version, though it's possible that the order matters and you have to put version Variable on the left hand side (or the right hand side).